# swift3での動画再生時にコントロールバーを使いたい

Tags: swift

swift3で動画再生をしています。デフォルトであるコントロールバーを表示してシークなどさせたいと思っていますが、下記のようなサンプルコードを動かしてみました。
動画をタップしてもコントロールバーの表示ができません。何かパラメータなど必要なのでしょうか。
ご存知の方はご教示お願いします。

```
let videoURL = NSURL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
player.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

iOSでの`AVPlayer`クラスはMVCで言うところのController要素にあたり、表示画面(あなたのコードなら`AVPlayerLayer`)や再生ボタンなどを置いたコントロールバーなどのView要素は含まれておらず、他の要素と組み合わせて使うことが想定されたクラスです。

システム標準のコントロールバーで良いのなら、`AVPlayer`単独ではなく`AVPlayerViewController`と組み合わせて使うことになります。

```
    let videoURL = URL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")!
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
    let playerVC = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerVC.player = player
    player.play()
    present(playerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

`AVPlayerViewController`はstoryboardに配置することもできる(storyboardエディター上は「AVKit Player View Controller」と表示される)ので、細かい書き方にはいろいろバリエーションがありますが、普通に「`AVPlayerViewController`」で検索すれば、日本語の記事も多数見つかるので、その中から使いやすそうなコードを探されれば良いでしょう。